# Excel Sumifs is casesensitiv on a different computer

Tags: excel, windows, formula, case-sensitive, sumifs

we're working with an excel sheet where we use SUMIFS.
We've a column for the criteria with values like "High" or "Low". Our SUMIFS function looks for "HIGH" in that column and since the function isn't case sensitive it works well.
However a collogue in turkey has the issue that the function doesn't work  because the function seems to be case sensitive on his computer.
Is this caused by the different language settings on his Windows/Excel installation? Or is there a setting in excel where you can switch the function to case sensitive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Turkish is one of those languages where the *length* of a string is sensitive to a case conversion.

So quite often you will find case sensitivity set to true in such a language.

You can force the issue yourself by using the function `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` in an Excel formula, making a case conversion at the point of use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what has the length of a string to do with case conversion?

Comment: Quite a lot. Much of the world doesn't *expect* the length of a string to change if the case changes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the word "HIGH" has more or less letters for the system than "High" in turkish?